# Where does Spring Boot store its default logging settings

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, logback

I'm creating a Java Spring Boot 2.X application. In my configuration (application.yml), I have added the following property:

```
logging:
    file: ${spring.applicaton.name}.log
```

This seems to work out of the box. However, I'm curious where the underlying default log configurations reside. Using google I found out that Spring Boot uses logback, but I cannot see a logback-spring.xml file. Also [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36544980/default-spring-boot-log4j2-log-pattern) seems to mention log4j2 instead of logback - does that work because they added a dependency on log4j2 (I have not added any dependency except for the sprint boot starter). what I also observed is that the two main logging mechanisms seem to be a rolling file appender and the console logger. Where is this defined?

My question is: where does Spring Boot pick up its default log configuration? I found [these configuration files](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/resources/org/springframework/boot/logging/logback) but I'm not sure if they are correct. Their naming convention and syntax is not what I expected. how do you choose a specific logging implementation - by dependencies or by configuration?

Comment: If you read the configuration files, you'll see this comment: *equivalent to the programmatic initialization performed by Boot*, which implies that the configuration is done programmatically, with Java code, and not using a configuration file.

Comment: @JBNizet Are these programmatical defaults not documented? If they are not, which class or which package contains the relevant code?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-logging

Comment: *"How do you choose a specific logging implementation?"* [Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-custom-log-configuration)

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) configuration is stored in:

```
spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar
    /org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml
```

The default [Log4j2](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) configuration is stored in:

```
spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar
    /org/springframework/boot/logging/log4j2/log4j2-file.xml
```

The default [Java Util Logging](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html) configuration is stored in:

```
spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar
    /org/springframework/boot/logging/java/logging-file.properties
```

*Note: The version of the jar file varies, of course.*

Spring defaults to Logback. Read the [**Spring documentation**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.logging) for how to specify a different implementation and for how to configure it.

Comment: Please update this answer by linking to chapter 26 of the documentation, as that file explains in greater detail when a certain configuration is used and why.